# Displaying calculations using a loop in Python

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to write code that takes user input on the speed and travel time of a vehicle. Using this info the total distance per hour is calculated. A sample of the desired output if the user enters a speed of 30 MPH and a time of 4 hours would show the 4 hours and a distance of 30 hour 1, 60 for hour 2, 90 for hour 3, etc.

However, the code below produces output that just displays the final numbers. Meaning (using the input from above) it only shows hour 4 and the 120 miles distance four times.

This is the code:

```
#This program uses a loop to display
#distance traveled over time.

print('This program calculates distance traveled')
print('for a vehicle traveling at a constant speed.')

#Gets speed of the vehicle 
speed = int(input('Enter the vehicle speed in MPH: '))

#Gets the hours
hours = int(input('Enter time of trip in hours: '))

#creates headings for table displaying output
print()
print('Hour\tDistance Traveled')
print('-------------------------')


for number in range(1, hours + 1):
    distance = hours*speed
    print(hours, '\t', distance)
```

Comment: Change `hours` to `number` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using the terminal value (`hours`) in the calculation instead of the cycle variable (`number`).

If you change `hours` to `number` in the loop it will work as you expect.

```
for number in range(1, hours + 1):
    distance = number*speed
    print(number, '\t', distance)
```

Additionally, naming a variable `number` is a very bad practice. It is hard to understand what kind of number it is without reading through the entire code, therefore i would also suggest to rename it to something more informative, such as `intermediate_hour` or just `hour`:

```
for intermediate_hour in range(1, hours + 1):
    distance = intermediate_hour * speed
    print(intermediate_hour, '\t', distance)
```